# Docker --platform vs. Docker's 'Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon' Beta feature

Tags: docker, apple-m1, rosetta

I found an interesting phenomenon which I need help with understanding.

#### Context

I am trying to run MSSQL Docker container (https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server).

```
Machine: Macbook Air
Chip: M1
OS: Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261)

Docker Version 4.19.0 (106363)
Engine: Engine: 23.0.5
```

#### Behaviour

If I were to run the image with the `--platform` flag, it produces this error:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: Invalid mapping of address 0x400384a000 in reserved address space below 0x400000000000.
```

However, if I run enable the beta feature 'Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon'. I can run without error.

#### Question

I was looking around to find out what Docker use to emulate the environment to run containers built with a different processor architecture. I have seen information on how emulation is done using QEMU and others saying its Rosetta 2. But if Rosetta is already used for emulation, then:

1. Why is there a need for this beta feature?
2. Why is there a different behaviour before and after activating the beta feature? What is this difference?